# Returning data from asynchronous tasks in Java

Tags: java, asynchronous, implementation

I'm having trouble working with async callbacks in Java/Android.

Currently, the object that handles my network calls looks like this:

```
class Reciever {
    ...
    public String getData(String params) {
        ...
        networkLibrary.runInBackground(String url, new networkCallback() {
            public void done(String data, Exception e) { 
                // do something 
            };
        };
```

What I'd like to be able to do is, in another object, make a call like:

```
data = reciever.getData();
doSomethingWith(data);
```

Is there a different strategy I should be trying here?

Answer (score 0):

You should look into a [`Future`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) implementation in your async and callback methods.

EDIT: For a concrete implementation, look into [`FutureTasks`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html)